# Python: Current UTC plus 30 minutes

Tags: python, unix-timestamp, epoch

In Python, how can you get the current UTC time plus 30 minutes?

I tried this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> future = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=30*60)
>>> str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=future))
'16133 days, 17:54:08' ----> output
```

I'm not sure this is correct (I'm sure I am wrong, Python newb here).

Comment: Now gives you your local time not the UTC time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
(datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=60*30)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 4, 18, 0, 49, 757000)
```

Comment: awesome! Thank you! how would you convert this to seconds?

Comment: @dennismonsewicz, If you use Python 3.3+, you can use [`datetime.datetime.timestamp()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) to get POSIX timestamp.

Comment: seconds since what? Epoch is 1970, which is what a lot of things use.  Or do you want since 0 C.E.? Or since Tuesday when Jimmy swallowed a snail because of a dare.

Comment: @JeffLangemeier - I need to publish a `start_date` that looks like this: 2014-03-10T12:00:00Z or it could be presented in seconds like this: 1394452800

Comment: @dennismonsewicz, Try `datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()` or `datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%SZ')`